# What law applies in the case of a theft at a Border Patrol checkpoint? Who can make an arrest?

Tags: united-states, jurisdiction, theft, borders

Travelers A and B are waiting in line at a border patrol checkpoint, when traveler B attempts to steal something of traveler A's. Can a Border Patrol officer intervene, or would they have to summon a state/city/county peace officer? Would the crime be prosecuted and tried under federal law or state law?

Comment: Why is Colorado tagged? It doesn't have a border. Are you asking about airports?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- Sure. I just tagged Colorado because it's my home state.

Comment: What relevance does Colorado have to the question?

Comment: Are you asking about internal checkpoints operated by the US Border Patrol or external border ports of entry operated by Customs and Border Protection field officers?

Answer (score 1):

> Can a Border Patrol officer intervene

Yes.

> Would they have to summon a state/city/county peace officer?

If no federal law was violated (see below), then yes.  If both federal and state laws were violated then they could still choose to let the state take the case.

> Would the crime be prosecuted and tried under federal law or state law?

State law, most likely.  Federal laws against [theft](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/part-I/chapter-31) and [robbery](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/part-I/chapter-103) apply only in certain specific contexts.

Comment: [like, the lectern from the capitol](https://loweringthebar.net/2021/01/assorted-stupidity-140-sedition-edition.html)

Comment: What about the Assimilated Crimes Act?

Comment: @moonman239 it's not clear to me whether the [Assimilative Crimes Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assimilative_Crimes_Act) would apply -- it probably wouldn't to people waiting on the highway behind a USBP checkpoint, but maybe it would to those inside the checkpoint facility or to those at a port of entry.  There is still concurrent jurisdiction at those places, however, so the feds could let the state take over, as mentioned in the answer.  In other words, where the ACA applies it affects the analysis of the condition "if federal law was violated" but otherwise doesn't change the answer.